Деплой backend части веб приложения
После деплоя backend части веб приложения у меня возникли несколько вопросов, которые по идее должны были возникнуть задолго до этого, так вот, 1 вопрос) должен ли я устанавливать ssl сертификат для backend части или это надо только для frontend части. 2 вопрос) вот есть ip-адрес, перейдя по которой мы попадем на apiroot(у меня бэк написан на django), и как-то это не кошерно, должен ли любой пользователь, зная адрес попасть в грубо говоря в backend  часть web-приложения. 3вопрос, связанный с 1) должен ли backend часть web приложения иметь домен или эта часть должна иметь просто ip адрес с постоянным портом


ssl защищает соединение между сервером и клиентом, а кем будет этот клиент (frontend или не frontend), не имеет значения, главное соединение защитить; 2) api должен быть спроектирован так, чтобы полное его знание кем угодно не создавало никаких проблем, к тому же многие сайты вполне официально имеют публичные api; 3) Сами решайте что вам удобнее — домен или ip, только вот для ip обычно не выдают ssl-сертификаты, а без них вы не сможете обеспечить ранее упомянутую защиту соединения


Смотря для кого у вас сайт. Сертфикат можно и самому сделать, если не нужна проверка подлинности. Тогда и домен не нужен.
